# flutter: Expected to find '}'. in if else condition

Tags: flutter, dart

In `GestureDetector` in onTap event i have a if condition like this:

```
Positioned(
  left: 1.0,
  top: -20.0,
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => {
      if (widget.status == RemoteStatus.edit)
        {
          showChooseProfileScreen(0).then((val) {
            if (val != null && val) {
              print("------> $val");
            }
          })
        }
      else {
        if (!onTapRaised)
        {
          sendCommand(54); //Expected to find '}'. error
          onTapRaised = true;
          releaseTapRaised(onTapRaised);
        }
      }
    },
    child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 20.0),
```

Someone knows why i got error `Expected to find '}'.` in sendCommand(54); part?

[image]

I run flutter clean before but i still got this error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change

```dart
onTap: () => {
```

to

```dart
onTap: () {
```

Because otherwise Dart interprets it as if you were returning map literal, not executing set of instructions.

Example:

```dart
Map foo() => {'key': 'value'}; // returns Map
void bar() { print('just executes set of instructions'); } // returns void
```

Refer to [Functions](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#functions) section in the Language tour.